# Java exception out of memory

Tags: java

This is extremely strange. I am getting an out of memory exception when trying to create a file. However, there is more than enough space on the disk for the file to be created.

The application is running on a Citrix (not sure if that is even relevant).

I have no idea where to even start to debug this since I can clearly see that there is space on the disk.

The file I'm trying to create is 4 KB and named `history.db`

Any ideas here?

This is the code I'm using to create the file:

```
try {
    String databaseFileLocation = "";
    String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    String homeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File myAppDir = new File(homeDir, ".imbox");
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
        databaseFileLocation = "jdbc:sqlite:" + myAppDir + fileSeparator + "history_" + agentID + ".db";
    } else if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac")) {
        databaseFileLocation = "jdbc:sqlite:history_" + agentID + ".db";
    }
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseFileLocation);
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitorInfo (channelID text UNIQUE, currentPage, userCountry, userCity, org);");
    stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS chatHistory (channelID, sender, message, recipient, time);");
    stat.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE visitorInfo ADD COLUMN visitorTag;");
} catch (Exception eef) {
    eef.printStackTrace();

    final ImageIcon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/warning_icon.gif"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to create database file.\n\nError description:\n" + eef.getMessage(), "Error when creating database file", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, icon);

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: What kind of out of memory error. What does the stack trace show. Can you also post the VM arguments (related to memory)

Comment: Well, out of memory exception are not really realted to disk space, more about if the JVM can hold the objects in memory which you want to store to file. More probable is an endless loop which keeps allocating new memory until you run oom.

Comment: I've posted the code above

Comment: Could you attache exception's stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortunately i cant get the stacktrace, this is a customer who is running the compiled code on the machine. I dont have access to the machine :/

Comment: Well, but you surely do a lot more than write a file. Loading a SQL driver can consume a lot of memory. So if your VM is rather short on memory, a lot can happen. Also I do not see any code closing those statements and sql connection. This is also shouting for a memory leak.

Comment: So, how do you know that the exception is thrown when creting the file?

Comment: Im not sure what line is causing this, I've asked the customer to give me access to the machine so i can get some more info here

Comment: How is the app launched? The last time I had a mysterious memory issue in a GUI app I had missed the unit from my heap size parameter and allocated a few bytes, rather than a few gigabytes. You should check that sort of thing. Also, use logging!

Comment: Could it help to increase the `head size` ?

Answer (score 0):

I can only say so much given such a small piece of code and no stack trace but judging by how this code is written I'll make a few assumptions.

Resources are being opened and never closed here, if that is happening here I can imagine that the same thing is happening elsewhere in the code.   If that's the case then it's likely that there's some other unsafe code around.

This means with such little information the best I can say is that if the code has been running a while that you have a memory leak in there somewhere, probably using resources.  If this has been started and restarted more than a few times then it's probably not being closed cleanly and old versions of this program are hanging around.

To properly figure this out, we would either need more code and/or a stack trace.  Possibly running jps on the machine would help as well, otherwise we don't have enough information to say more.